# SharePoint 2013 Migration from 2007 and 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, 2007, migration

I have some data in MOSS 2007 and some in SharePoint 2010. I am planning to migrate to SharePoint 2013. The amount of data is around 50GB. I don't want the entire content DB.

I am planning to use a third party tool. I have a maximum of $2000 to spend on a  tool. I contacted Metalogix and ShareGate and it doesn't look like that will work for me. Can any one suggest the other good third party tools or any other options?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a third party tool?!
You can migrate the site directly from 2007 to 2010 and then from 2010 to 2013. Read [this article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee947141.aspx).

Comment: Probably because he wants a selective migration of content of 2 farms, not the entire content from both farms.

Comment: True but 50GB is hardly going to take much time, and OOTB methods will certainly save him those 2K $. And then you could always go and delete the content you don't want. So I don't get the reason for preferring TPA over OOTB.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [xplica](http://www.vyapin.com/products/sharepoint-to-sharepoint/xplica/sharepoint-migration-tools-and-software) with success. I don't recall the price, but I think it may have been in that range.